# What IS the precise angle of repose of Cadbury Creme Eggs, anyways?

Tags: forces, friction

So, in *[What If](https://what-if.xkcd.com/148/)*, made by xkcd guy Randall Munroe, an off-handed joke about his famous love of Cadbury Creme Eggs was made.

[image]

In the image's mouseover text, Randall jokes his life's dream is to own enough Cadbury Eggs to determine their precise angle of repose.

For those who don't know, an object's **[angle of repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose)** is *the angle of the slope of a pile of that thing on the ground.* Here's a subpar MS Paint reference.

[image]

So, at room temperature, with the wrappers on, **what is the precise angle of repose for a standard Cadbury Creme Egg?**

Comment: With foil wrappers or without? It'd affect the friction.

Comment: @innisfree temperature would also have an effect... if it was nice and warm there would be significant additional adhesion.

Comment: Predicting the properties of granular materials is notoriously difficult. There is little change of doing this from first principles. You'd have to do the experiment.

Comment: innisfree and IanF1: Question conditions refined.

John Rennie: Right. This question is sort of aimed at the sad sort who knows a lot about physics, but is still stuck in a Cadbury factory (or just really likes Cadbury Creme eggs).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Packaging engineer here who legitimately needed the answer to this question. The answer is roughly 25 degrees. Note the angle of repose is defined from the ground plane, opposite to your diagram.

[image: experimental setup]

[image: angle of repose for cadbury creme eggs]

I suppose this makes me the sad engineer stuck in a Cadbury factory.

Comment: Well, color me pleasantly surprised! Seven long years, three US presidential administrations, a global pandemic, and a new land war in Europe later and finally... finally someone on the internet has gathered enough creme eggs into one place to grace us with this answer. You're a hero, MacLain.

Comment: Uhm... by the looks of it, wouldn't this answer be different if you were to constrain the eggs of the floor, i.e. prevent them from just rolling away on the floor? But shouldn't the correct answer be independent of friction on the base plate? If so, wouldn't the true angle actually be steeper?

Comment: I gotta ask: do you actually work for Cadbury, or just manage a teenage football team that just gets their pre-game energy boost from Cadbury eggs?  … and there I was thinking the [secret of the Caramilk](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=46yUz1sJ4MgO) was the ultimate mystery.